# Change the default font styles for a wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages, font

I'm trying to change the default heading 1, 2 & 3 for every new wiki page that is created on my site.

Also I would like new pages to start with embedded code that creates the layout of a table of contents.

Does anyone have any idea on how that is accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharePoint Framework Extension Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) to load/ inject a custom CSS in your page, where the custom CSS can be stored in one of the document libraries in your SharePoint site.

Please check out [this article](https://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2019/05/03/change-styles-in-sharepoint-online-modern-pages/) which describes the common issues about SharePoint online branding using custom css and the possible options.

Here is a [demo project](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss) to inject a custom CSS. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After customizing in the page, you can save the page as a template to make the new page based on the template you want.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-online-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us